# Class's operator() or bind a function as a functor?

Tags: performance, c++11, coding-style, functor

There are two ways to make a functor (a function that holds a state):

1. bind a function and define a state: `bind(f, _1, state)`

   double g(double x, double state) {
     return x+state;
   }
   function f = bind(g,_1,state);
2. use `()` operator and a class:

```
struct f { 
  double state; 
  f(double state_):state(state_) {} 
  double operator()(double x) {return x+state;}
};
```

I find that `bind`-method is faster to write but I'm wondering if there are some hidden stones since most of the time in literature I see functor as class's `()` operator.

Comment: What is the `f` in your `std::bind(f, _1, state)`?

Comment: What `std::bind` does is basically create an object like in your second case. So in reality there's really not much of a difference. The second is much more common in books etc. since `std::bind` and C++11 still is quite new.

Comment: Since this is tagged with C+11, there is another way, lambda functions with capture.

Answer (score 3):

The 3. way is a lambda expression:

```
auto f = [state]( double x ) { return x * state; };
```

Comment: it's a good quick solution but I don't see how you would use it in different functions. doesn't seem to be modular -- you have to define state in definition of the function. in the other 2, you define the function in a separate module and define the state at initialization.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `bind` is inspired from functional languages (as the header filename tells you).
I think it's quite equivalent because it's a template function, but maybe optimized by build-in calls...

It's the first time I see this function, so I'll need to look the asm to see the difference, then I'll repost ;)

Nevertheless, It doesn't allow you to have other methods in your functor, so `operator()` is still needed for many uses

**[EDIT]**
Okay, I saw the asm : bind adds a lot of code because of its templates in comparison to the "classic way". Thus, I advise you to use the strucs ways to your use (i.e. just a functor). Moreover, it's more understandable to read a such code.
Bind is good if you take profit af the substitution of parameter but for simple use, it's a laser canon to cut your cheese :P
**[/EDIT]**

Comment: i get the same speed if I use -O2 optimization. did you look at asm with or without optimization. thanks for looking

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `struct` is the faster way to do it:

```
11:01:56 ~/try 
> g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp ; ./a.out
in 2265 ms, functor as a struct result = 1.5708e+16
in 31855 ms, functor through bind result = 1.5708e+16
11:02:33 ~/try 
> clang++ -std=c++11 main.cpp ; ./a.out
in 3484 ms, functor as a struct result = 1.5708e+16
in 21081 ms, functor through bind result = 1.5708e+16
```

the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::placeholders;
using namespace std::chrono;

struct fs {
  double s;
  fs(double state) : s(state) {}
  double operator()(double x) {
    return x*s;
  }
};

double fb(double x, double state) {
  return x*state;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  double state=3.1415926;

  const auto stp1 = system_clock::now();
  fs fstruct(state);
  double sresult;
  for(double x=0.0; x< 1.0e8; ++x) {
    sresult += fstruct(x);
  }
  const auto stp2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
  const auto sd = duration_cast<milliseconds>(stp2 - stp1);  
  cout << "in " << sd.count() << " ms, "; 
  cout << "functor as a struct result = " << sresult << endl;

  const auto btp1 = system_clock::now();
  auto fbind = bind(fb, _1, state);
  double bresult;
  for(double x=0.0; x< 1.0e8; ++x) {
    bresult += fbind(x);
  }
  const auto btp2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
  const auto bd = duration_cast<milliseconds>(btp2 - btp1);  
  cout << "in " << bd.count() << " ms, "; 
  cout << "functor through bind result = " << bresult << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

**Update (1)**

one can also have function as a function object:

```
struct fbs {
  double operator()(double x, double state) const {
    return x*state;
  }
};
```

and in the main.cpp:

```
  const auto bstp1 = system_clock::now();
  auto fbindstruct = bind(fbs(), _1, state);
  double bsresult;
  for(double x=0.0; x< 1.0e8; ++x) {
    bsresult += fbindstruct(x);
  }
  const auto bstp2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
  const auto bsd = duration_cast<milliseconds>(bstp2 - bstp1);  
  cout << "in " << bsd.count() << " ms, "; 
  cout << "functor through bind-struct result = " << bsresult << endl;
```

didn't change the speed:

```
> g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp ; ./a.out
hi
in 2178 ms, functor as a struct result = 1.5708e+16
in 31972 ms, functor through bind result = 1.5708e+16
in 32083 ms, functor through bind-struct result = 1.5708e+16
12:15:27 ~/try 
> clang++ -std=c++11 main.cpp ; ./a.out
hi
in 3758 ms, functor as a struct result = 1.5708e+16
in 23503 ms, functor through bind result = 1.5708e+16
in 23508 ms, functor through bind-struct result = 1.5708e+16
```

**Update (2)**

Adding optimization results in similar times:

```
> g++ -std=c++11 -O2 main.cpp ; ./a.out
hi
in 536 ms, functor as a struct result = 1.5708e+16
in 510 ms, functor through bind result = 1.5708e+16
in 472 ms, functor through bind-struct result = 1.5708e+16
12:31:33 ~/try 
> clang++ -std=c++11 -O2 main.cpp ; ./a.out
hi
in 388 ms, functor as a struct result = 1.5708e+16
in 419 ms, functor through bind result = 1.5708e+16
in 456 ms, functor through bind-struct result = 3.14159e+16
```

GCC 4.8.1 and Clang 3.3

**note** Clang 3.3 gives a wrong result for "bind-struct" case

**Update(3)**

there are more performance testing at [Is there a macro-based adapter to make a functor from a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175309/is-there-a-macro-based-adapter-to-make-a-functor-from-a-class)

Comment: your benchmark is not really significant, because there is many many case : bind can be use with a variable number of arguments, to be exhaustive, you'd need to check according to the number of arguments. 
But, it's not all, there is some uses that are not the functions.
see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bind/

Comment: this was just to get a starting idea. from the answer, I'd use bind because it's faster to write a prototype then I would measure other options if i need to optimize further.