# Is there a macro-based adapter to make a functor from a class?

Tags: c++, functor

Creating a functor requires an unnecessary boiler plate. The state has to be written 4 times!

```
struct f{
  double s; // 1st
  f(double state): s(state) {} // 2nd, 3rd and 4th
  double operator() (double x) {
    return x*s;
  }
};
```

is there a library with a macro that would be just `double functor(state)(x){ return x*state; }` or something similar.

`BOOST_FOREACH` is a macro adapter that works well. I'm looking for something similar.

any suggestions on how to write one is appreciated too.

ps. using struct for functor is faster then bind [Class's operator() or bind a function as a functor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169838/classs-operator-or-bind-a-function-as-a-functor)

**Update(1)**

in regards to lambdas:

the functor has to be modular, meaning, it should be reusable in other function. lambdas have to be within a function -- lambda has to be in main to be called from main and other functions outside of main, can't call the lambda defined in main.

Comment: I find `[s](double x){return x*s;}` to be reasonably terse.

Comment: @Casey it's not a modular solution that you can use in other functions.

Answer (score 4):

How about relying on aggregate initialization? Simply do not declare the constructor:

```
struct f {
    double s;
    double operator()(double x) {
        return x * s;
    }
};
```

use it like this

```
int main()
{       
    auto ff = f{42};
    std::cout << ff(2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: awesome! same speed. gcc was fine but clang gave a different result. `struct afr {
  double s;
  double operator() (double x) {
    return x*s;
  }
};
` and called as `afr af{state};
  double aresult;
  for(double x=0.0; x< 1.0e8; ++x) {
    aresult += af(x);
  }`. g++'s result was 1.5708e+16 (correct) and clang's was 4.71239e+16

Comment: how do you call it within algorithms? for example, `generate(v.begin(),v.end(), f{42}());` <-- doesn't work.

Comment: @kirill_igum `generate(v.begin(), v.end(), f{42});`

Comment: oops, my mistake. i should use `transform` instead of `generate`.

Answer (score 2):

Define the functionality you want, e.g., you multiplication, as a function and then use `std::bind()` to create a suitable function object:

```
#include <functional>

double some_operation(double state, double x) {
    return state * x;
}

int main() {
    auto function = std::bind(&some_operation, 17, std::placeholders::_1);
    return function(18);
}
```

Since a call through a function pointer generally can't be inlined, you might want to write your function as a function object instead:

```
#include <functional>

struct some_operation {
    double operator()(double state, double x) const {
        return state * x;
    }
};

int main() {
    auto function = std::bind(some_operation(), 17, std::placeholders::_1);
    return function(18);
}
```

Below is a test program which seems to indicate that the speed of a hand-crafted function object and a bound function object are about the same, i.e., the results I get are

```
in 90 ms, functor as a struct; result = 1.5708e+16
in 262 ms, function pointer through bind; result = 1.5708e+16
in 261 ms, function through bind; result = 1.5708e+16
in 87 ms, function object through bind; result = 1.5708e+16
in 88 ms, non-called bind with function; result = 1.5708e+16
in 88 ms, non-called bind with function pointer; result = 1.5708e+16
```

using a recent version of [clang](http://clang.llvm.org) (more precisely: `clang version 3.4 (trunk 182411)`) on a MacOS system optimizing with `-O2` option. Using and [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org) (more precisely: `gcc version 4.9.0 20130811 (experimental) (GCC)`) gives similar results.

It seems it makes a difference whether the function object is build in the local context or passed via template argument to a separate function. This difference is interesting as I would expect that most of the uses of `bind()` a function will result in passing off the resulting function object somewhere.

The code is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/18175033/1120273:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::placeholders;
using namespace std::chrono;

struct fs {
    double s;
    fs(double state) : s(state) {}
    double operator()(double x) {
        return x*s;
    }
};

struct ff {
    double operator()(double x, double state) const {
        return x * state;
    }
};

double fb(double x, double state) {
    return x*state;
}

template <typename Function>
void measure(char const* what, Function function)
{
    const auto stp1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    double sresult(0.0);
    for(double x=0.0; x< 1.0e8; ++x) {
        sresult += function(x);
    }
    const auto stp2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    const auto sd = duration_cast<milliseconds>(stp2 - stp1);  
    cout << "in " << sd.count() << " ms, "; 
    cout << what << "; result = " << sresult << endl;
}


int main() {
  double state=3.1415926;

  measure("functor as a struct", fs(state));
  measure("function through bind", std::bind(&fb, _1, state));
  measure("function object through bind", std::bind(ff(), _1, state));


  {
      const auto stp1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
      double sresult(0.0);
      auto function = std::bind(fb, _1, state);
      for(double x=0.0; x< 1.0e8; ++x) {
          sresult += function(x);
      }
      const auto stp2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
      const auto sd = duration_cast<milliseconds>(stp2 - stp1);  
      cout << "in " << sd.count() << " ms, "; 
      cout << "embedded bind with function; result = " << sresult << endl;
  }
  {
      const auto stp1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
      double sresult(0.0);
      auto function = std::bind(&fb, _1, state);
      for(double x=0.0; x< 1.0e8; ++x) {
          sresult += function(x);
      }
      const auto stp2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
      const auto sd = duration_cast<milliseconds>(stp2 - stp1);  
      cout << "in " << sd.count() << " ms, "; 
      cout << "embedded bind with function pointer; result = " << sresult << endl;
  }    

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: this would be great but it's 10x slower http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169838/classs-operator-or-bind-a-function-as-a-functor

Comment: Yes, calling through a function pointer can't be inlined. Whether it matters depends on what you do in your function. Using a function object and binding it should be as fast as implementing the wrapper yourself, though.

Comment: same speed as bind http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169838/classs-operator-or-bind-a-function-as-a-functor

Comment: Are you compiling with optimization turned on? I get different results (see my answer). Without optimization I get similar figures as you do, i.e., using `bind()` is always slow but this just shows that you want to enable optimization rather than not using the correct approach.

Comment: good call! i thought `-O2` was default. I actually get the same speed for just bind on both g++ and clang++. can you include the compiler's versions in your answer.

Comment: I compiled the code using a recent version of the clang repository (clang version 3.4 (trunk 182411)). I wouldn't pay too much attention to the apparently slightly faster result of the approach using `bind()`: based on the test made I would call it a measurement error rather than a real effect. ... or you mean you get the same speed for all three versions of the code?

Comment: That's interesting. There are two subtle differences between your and my test: 1. I'm passing the function by function pointer which seems to make it slightly faster; 2. I'm calling a function rather than building the entire object where it is used, too. It turns out that this does have performance impact! (I'll update my answer in a moment)

Comment: "Since a call through a function pointer generally can't be inlined, you might want to write your function as a function object instead:" You could reduce the (slight) boilerplate of the `struct` by binding the function `some_operation` to a non-type template parameter (of an appropriate class template). Without a macro, the binding could look like `std::bind(function_object<decltype(fb)&,fb>(), _1, state)` and should have the same performance as the *function object* approach.

Comment: @DyP: the code I used for profiling is above: did you give it a try? That said, the problem isn't the pointer vs. reference but rather the indirection. When using a function pointer or reference the compiler needs to see through the bind to see that the function being bound is always the same to potentially inline it.

Comment: Yes, I tried it with an [online g++4.8.1](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=8466c03f9f3eb1f491e2d57c2d6e96ed-0fb4dfbfff1f3337334935fbcdeaf46c). As the non-type template parameter is known at compile time, the compiler should be able to inline the call, and the results (with `-O2`) seem to indicate it does. I originally used a function pointer, but it requires typing one more character in the bind call ;)

Answer (score 0):

We've got lambdas for this:

```
double s = 42;
auto f = [s](double x) {
    return s * x;  
};
```

Down to single mention of state on line 2 (as you dont seem to count one in the actual expression). Whether initialization on line 1 counts as mention is debatable, your desired form does not contain any initialization, which is required, so I assume this to be acceptable.

In c++14 we'll get extension of lambda capture syntax allowing even more terse form:

```
auto f = [s{42}](double x) {
    return s * x;  
};
```

Comment: I already addressed it in the comment. lambdas are not modular. I also updated the question for clarity.

Comment: @kirill_igum "it should be reusable in other function. lambdas have to be within a function" - this is simply wrong. You can declare lambda object at namespace scope just like any other variable and use it wherever. It is true however that you can not initialize state to different values.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [BOOST_LOCAL_FUNCTION](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/local_function/doc/html/index.html) which seems to be exactly what youre looking for, as you even mention a macro :)

```
double s = 42;
double BOOST_LOCAL_FUNCTION(bind& s, double x) {
  return x*s;
} BOOST_LOCAL_FUNCTION_NAME(f)
```

*Personal note: If you have a modern compiler, go with C++11 lambdas.*